# Most effecient way to count number of 1's from a certain offset

Tags: scala

If I have a given integer say 584,091,081 what is the most efficient way to count the number of ones from a given offset say n.

So for the example number given the offset = 6 the first  couple of bits are 11001001.

So I would want the answer 0. Because after the 6 bit comes a 1.

If however we saw 100001001 then the expected answer would be 2 because there are 2 zeroes before the next one.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: Also, how is this relevant to scala specifically? Or do you need a solution explicitly in scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
java.lang.Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(x >>> offset)
```

(or `(offset - 1)` if you count from 1 instead of 0).